# ^M is added in the spark output

Tags: apache-spark

i have a json file as input(its a zip file with multiple json files in it) and the spark job (spark 2.3) does some processing and delivers csv files as output

I have "^M" (windows newline) being appended in the output files which is not present in the input

i read the file as follows, appending schema to it.

```
Dataset<Row> ds = session.read().schema(createSchema()).option("multiLine", true).json(inputPath.split(","));
```

example of bad record

```
Encarnacion Ari'El,,,Building a Geological Cyber-infrastructure: Automatically detecting^MClasts in Photomicrographs,,
```

any help here would be appreciated

Comment: are you sure that ^M is not present into the json input file too? It seems to me that it is part of the textual description of the "Cyber-infrastructrue" field

Comment: ok i just figured out in the source json there is "\r" appended, 

so the bad record in the source looks like "Cyber-infrastructure: Automatically detecting\rClasts in Photomicrographs" which gets translated to "^M" in the output csv files, i have earlier removed "\n" with dataset.na().fill(""), can you suggest how to remove "\r"?

Comment: can't you just use the same technique used to remove \n to remove \r too ?

Comment: ok found the solution, no we cant use na().fill() to remove "\r", i did give it a try.
following is the solution that worked

    Dataset.withColumn("title", functions.translate(col("title"), "\n\r", " "))

we can use the same solution to replace other special characters that may occur by just appending it to the translate function, like i have appended "\n" with "\r"